# Recommended Redis data eviction policy for Craft CMS

Tags: craft3, cache, redis

I have recently switched from memcached to Redis. The cache, session, template caching and mutex is now using Redis on a project. While Redis generally gets managed by Yii/Craft CMS, Redis features a few more configuration options than memcached, so I was looking for any further insight/advice on the best configuration when used with Craft CMS.

The current data eviction policy which seems to be a default for most Redis provisioning is `volatile-lru`. There are other eviction policies available:

- noeviction: New values aren’t saved when memory limit is reached. When a database uses replication, this applies to the primary database
- allkeys-lru: Keeps most recently used keys; removes least recently used (LRU) keys
- allkeys-lfu: Keeps frequently used keys; removes least frequently used (LFU) keys
- volatile-lru: Removes least recently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- volatile-lfu: Removes least frequently used keys with the expire field set to true.
- allkeys-random: Randomly removes keys to make space for the new data added.
- volatile-random: Randomly removes keys with expire field set to true.
- volatile-ttl: Removes keys with expire field set to true and the shortest remaining time-to-live (TTL) value.

Based on my own assessment `allkeys-lru`, `allkeys-lfu`, `volatile-lru` and `volatile-lfu` and likely the best options, but any Redis experts care to comment on their take?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my own assessment and looking at other resources, `allkeys-lru` is likely the best policy to use in many cases.

https://redis.io/docs/manual/eviction/